# Perform Post request (Json) using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST request using Volley that contains a json body I notice this library has other related question on S.O but do NOT address my particular use case appropriately. My team and I have tried different workarounds with no success.

I have tried different variations of the code presented and cannot get anything working in the context of sending something contained in the body. What I'm trying to do is (1) post (2) in that post include a base64 in that body. I should mention the endpoint, in this case, is working and have confirmed with network interceptors as well as looking at the back end this is indeed sending no data in the body.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private Uri capturedImageUri = null;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    final Context context = this;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        Button btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            String convertedIMG = convertImage(photo);
            sendToRemote(convertedIMG);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could Not Capture Image, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private String sendToRemote(String sendImage) {
        String url = "localhost:3000/medicalImage";
        try {

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d("Response: >", response); /// put this on the UI wil contain the percentage of accuracy if positive

                        }
                    },

                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //  imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.d("network", "=========>", error);
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Submitting Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private String convertImage(Bitmap photo) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        byte[] b = out.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

CODE WE USED BELOW-------------------------------------------------------

```
 private void sendToRemote(final String sendImage) {
     String url = "url";
     try {

         JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
         jsonBody.put("Image", sendImage);
         requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                 new Response.Listener<String>() {

                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(String response) {
                         // Log.d("Response: >", response);
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Prediction "
                                 + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // returns percent of assumption
                     }
                 },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         //Log.d("network", "=========>", error);
                         error.printStackTrace();
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Submitting Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }

                 }) {

             @Override
             public String getBodyContentType() {
                 return String.format("application/json; charset=utf-8");
             }

             @Override
             public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                 try {

                     return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                     return null;
                 }
             }
         };
         RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
         queue.add(stringRequest);
     } catch (Exception error) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unexpected Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         error.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using JsonObjectRequest? It takes an object parameter to POST

Answer (score 0):

To add a parameter you have to override getParams(), like so:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response: >", response); /// put this on the UI wil contain the percentage of accuracy if positive

                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //  imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("network", "=========>", error);
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Submitting Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("your-key", your-data);
                        return params;
                    }
    };
```

Comment: Ok interesting. So just to clarify with this particular lib the annotations in our case is essentially what is adding the body to the http request. Are you sure the method you suggested adds this to the body? I must say this library uses a very different approach comparing to the fetch or Angular http requests.

Comment: Yes, to POST you have to override getParams() and return a Map<k, v>.

Comment: You need to add headers to make this send JSON, though

Comment: That pointed me on the right track thank you but ultimately it was still not sending the post request, the response was always empty. I will include the code I used below the other patch^ which ultimately is what we used to send the POST.